# Finding height of a non-binary tree

Tags: c++, tree

I was doing exercises in a website and in exercise we must find height of a non-binary tree by implementing a function. I have a TreeNode class in below.

```
class TreeNode
{
public:
TreeNode();
TreeNode(string data);
void addChild(TreeNode* child);
vector<TreeNode*>& getChildren();
void setData(string data);
string getData();
void visit();
};
```

I implement this http://codepad.org/BiXkbABf. But this doesn't work. How can I implement this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int hight(TreeNode* node) {
    vector<TreeNode*>& children = node.getChildren();
    unsigned int h = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
        h = std::max(h, hight(children[i]));
    }
    return h + 1;
}
```

`return 1 + maxi`; is an error. you already accounting for the current node in `k = 1 + max(height((tree->getChildren)()[i]),height((tree->getChildren)()[i+1]));`

Answer (score 0):

The logic inside your loop is completely wrong. For some reason you're looking at pairs of consecutive children. Instead, you should look at one child at a time, and pick the one that has the largest height.

Comment: I see but, how can I stop without exiting function and look for other nodes?

Comment: For each child, you get their height, while keeping track of the largest height seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in this line; try to spot it yourself:

```
if(k>maxi)k=maxi;
```

Furthermore, although your overall approach should work, it performs more work than necessary because the height of almost the height of most subtrees get computed twice. You might want to rewrite the code to just compute each height once (hint: don't compare two heights directly; instead, store the height of the previous subtree in a variable and compare only one subtree's height to the variable).

Answer (score 0):

next place the following lines atop your source code; try to figure out what they are for and fix your code accordingly

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
```